# What Screwdriver to remove Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 Laptop Harddrive

Tags: hard-drive

I am following this video, https://youtu.be/6RMRw1QaZGk?t=42

I was able to remove two screws (in green using Phillips #1), but I am unable to remove two screws in red.

How do I unscrew and hense remove the hard-drive. I'm hoping to remove and place back before trying to start up my computer again (to confirm whether I need to purchase replacement hard drive).

[image]

Comment: Your machine is a 5221. The video was for a 5220.  They are different.  Try this video and see it that helps     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kilZIXIRD_0

Comment: @John Thank you for this video. Now I am trying to find out out to remove hard disk from caddy (or bracket). I am researching this but if you also find any resource, please post.

Comment: Video, 60% along, remove screws several at the "back" of the drive (follow closely), slide drive back, lift from front and remove.  That will do it.

Answer (score 1):

The green arrows show the two screws holding the drive in place. Once released, the drive will slide upward (relative to the photo position) while remaining flat to the main board. Once the drive has moved upward, the lower connection to the board will release. Lifting at that point will permit removal.

The red arrows point to screw holes which are "industry standard" for other mounting systems, as the hard drive can be used in computers from other manufacturers.

Comment: I think this would be a much better answer if you can clearly state that there are no screws where the red arrows are pointing. The screws that were removed were the only two screws holding things in place and at this point just sliding the drive up will release it.