# How so I find a new hard drive for my laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, dell-inspiron

The hard drive of my Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 laptop failed.

I went to Dell's website, entered my service tag number and it [suggested a compatible hard drive](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-500gb-72k-rpm-sata-512e-25in-hard-drive/apd/400-ahct/storage-drives-media): Dell 500GB 2.5in SATA 7,200rpm hard drive.

I purchased this hard drive but it did not have same two screws to anchor it into the cradle an when I turned on my laptop, it said, “No bootable device.”

I tried to get through Dell tech support and after being transferred four times, I decided to return it and I will be getting refund.

My question is, how do I find a hard drive that will not only fit into the laptop's cradle, but that I can anchor securely so the computer will boot up and work.

**Original Hard Drive**

[image]

**Screws that came with original hard drive in laptop**

[image]

**Original hard drive in laptop**

[image]

**The drive recommended by Dell - causes “no bootable device” error.**

[image]

Comment: So you seem to have two issues: When you installed the new drive, did it have an OS on it? if it has no OS on it, it is just an empty drive and won’t boot. Regarding the screws, the new drive mounting holes should be in the exact same position. These are not Dell specific drives but standard mounting hole positions. You seem to be having a bit of [confusion as to how drives connect in your system](https://superuser.com/q/1606573/167207) when these are just basic 2.5" hard drives.

Comment: Do you have a _real_ photo of the new disk, preferably inside your laptop? The one from the product's page isn't even the same type – it's a stock photo of a **3.5"** disk (which wouldn't fit in a laptop at all), so your arrows are pointing to nothing useful.

Comment: @user1686 I already returned the old hard drive. I wish I would have taken photo. I was just so upset.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Dell said that their hard drive would have an OS. It would boot and then pull updates from the Internet. How would I boot laptop with hard drive that does NOT have OS?

Comment: @Marium “Dell said that their hard drive would have an OS.” No manufacturers do this for replacement drives. “How would I boot laptop with hard drive that does NOT have OS?” You need to have the install CDs for the OS and then boot from the CD and then when it starts, it will detect the new disk as blank and ask if you want to use that drive for the new OS. Sorry to say, it might be best if you just go to a repair shop and ask them to replace the drive. All your questions point to you being a bit more lost than expected in dealing this this.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am in COVID lockdown :-(

Comment: @Marium Sorry to hear. But this is the summary: You do not have to purchase a special Dell hard drive. Any 2.5" sized laptop notebook/laptop hard drive will do. If you purchase a drive like that from Dell, they will charge you more. The mounting holes are 100% the same spacing on all of them. Usually if the holes don’t line up its because the drive’s SATA connector was not pushed in all the way to the connector on the notebook/laptop. As far as the OS goes that model Dell has a CD/DVD drive so you need to get Windows on CD. Boot from that CD and install the OS on the hard drive. That’s it.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 This is very helpful. I'll likely get a nice hard drive from Amazon during the Holidays (maybe after???). And I'm gonna create a bootable USB with an OS. Can you show me what is the SATA connector. Is it the drive, opposite of where the supposed screws are? Thank you for your patience in all of this.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am looking to get this one, https://www.amazon.com/500GB-Laptop-Solid-Hybrid-Inspiron/dp/B076CJ257K/. I presume it is internal

Comment: @Marium That drive looks fine. The SATA connector is what you push into the socket on the main board. Look at [this tutorial](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-upgrade-hdd-your-acer-nitro-5) and just look at how the drives are physically changed. That said, this site is not for questions like this at this level. I recommend you research online how to change a hard drive. It is not that hard, but you honestly seem very lost here. So I cannot help you any further. Take your time and research how to do this and you should be good.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Totally understand :-) Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 0):

[image]  This is where the screw goes, not where your arrow points.